# Is there any way on MSO to provide general feedback on SO?

Tags: discussion, meta

Is there any mechanism on MSO outside of asking/answering/commenting for someone to simply "provide feedback" on the SO site?  I'm not talking about feedback that someone wants/needs to keep private, I'm just talking about a means to capture user experience with the site that might otherwise be "lost" given the current framework.

Comment: "Provide feedback" with what goal? If it's simply to tell the SE employees how nice your day was, you can in theory use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page. If it's a topic that is related to more people than just you personally, it's probably either fit for a discussion, feature request, or support question on MSO. Hardly answerable without any example of the feedback you'd like to give.

Comment: I suppose goals might vary, but I was thinking of feedback about user experience that doesn't take the form of a question and for which there is no obvious question to answer or comment on (e.g. where no question can be found after a reasonable time spent searching).

Comment: Peter, from a semi-official perspective: Stijn's answer below (which I up voted) is pretty spot on!  If it involves security or anything personal from your perspective, use the "contact" page. If it's a suggestion or question about possible ways to improve the site, post them here on Meta.  Or on Meta SE if they definitely would apply network wide. One thing to be aware of, so it doesn't frustrate you - suggestions on meta that are thoughtful often still attract down votes, which folks use to indicate disagreement with the suggestion.

Comment: What kind of "user experience"? If it is a good experience then just keep enjoying the site. If it is a bad experience then tag as a discussion to get the thoughts of others. Your question is still a bit unclear.

Comment: This thread is somewhat ironic given my recent reaction on SO that caused me to want to "provide feedback". ;-)  In any event, I guess I'm talking primarily about negative user experience, although I suppose it could also apply to extraordinarily positive user experience.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, one more note - frustrating experiences are actually *very* helpful to share. We learn the most from what isn't working for some people. We'll take input anyway you care to give it, but if you want more constructive feedback from the community at large, focus on the possible solutions, or even just that you're trying to solicit help with solutions, or even understanding.  One thing that tends to bring out hostility is what feels like a rant without interest in finding improvement.  To be clear, it's obvious from your effort here that you *do* want to have constructive discussion.

Comment: If I get it right, you want to give some feedback, but it doesn't fit the Q&A format? Could you give an example of the kind of feedback you'd want to give?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Feedback that doesn't fit the Q&A format is a good example of feedback for which other mechanisms might be useful, although I am just simply asking about the existence of other mechanisms.

Comment: @Jaydles Actually, I didn't want to have a discussion about this. I really just wanted an answer to my question, just as sometimes I really do just want to provide feedback. :-)

Comment: It's usually not that difficult to turn your feedback into a question. For example, look at [meta-tag:burninate-request]. The message these askers want to convey is "I want to get rid of the ... tag". It is turned into things like "Do we really need the .... tag?"

Comment: Don't stare yourself blind on the Q&A format while you're on a Meta site. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta *"Meta is for: asking questions about how the websites work, asking questions of the community, posting bugs, suggesting improvements, proposing new features"*

Comment: @Stijn I'm not staring myself blind at all. I'll just choose not to participate in that way, just as I choose not to vote-to-close using close reasons that have all sorts of semantic inconsistencies.  Words matter to me and integrity between language, policies and behavior matters to me as well. But hey, maybe that's just me.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, but asking a question implies a response is being sought, which is often not the case.  Indeed, that's the fundamental difference between a statement and a question.. I think the most effective organizations/communities provide mechanisms to collect feedback that don't imply the person providing the feedback is seeking a response.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to give feedback on something that shouldn't be seen by the visitors of SO/MSO, for example a security issue, you can visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

All other feedback should be posted here. You can also post on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) if it concerns multiple sites, but it's not mandatory, you can post here if you prefer.

The sites are driven by the community, and although the team has the final say in everything, passing feedback by the community gives both us and the team a chance to openly review the feedback and prioritise it in relation to other feedback.